# Lync2013のUCMA4.0SDKでiPhoneで音声が流れない

Tags: c#, iphone, .net

こちらのブログを参考にしてLyncのアプリケーションを開発しています。
http://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=tsmatsuz&y=2011&m=08&d=27&WeblogPostName=ucma-3-0-lync-speech-voice-application-ivr-asr-tts&GroupKeys=

「声とテキストの変換処理 (ASR / TTS)」の項目で、クライアントがPCならば正しくテキストから合成された音声が流れるのですが、iPhoneだと何も聴こえずに通話が0秒のままで接続が切れます。

デバッグしたところ、下記の箇所が問題だと分かりました。

```
// Wait AudioVideo Flow activated
while (currentCall.Flow.State != MediaFlowState.Active)
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

の箇所でcurrentCall.Flow.StateがidleのままActiveになっていないようです。
解決方法をご存じの方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

また、SDKで作成したアプリケーションではなくOfficeの普通のLyncクライアント同士ですと、PCとiPhoneで通話やビデオのやり取りができました。

環境
　Lync2013
　UCMA 4.0 (Lyncと同じマシンにインストール)
　iPhone5s iOS8 (MSのLync2013アプリをインストール)
　Windowsのクライアントは8.1